# Too long execution for gradle test

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a Spring boot application that can be started in 10 seconds. However, in a simple empty integration test, I am getting horrible execution times (60-70 seconds). This is the same when using IntelliJ or `gradle test`. The initialization of spring context takes much much longer than running the service manually. Normally the app starts in 10 seconds, however in the gradle test for 50 seconds.

```
    120ms  :kaptKotlin
    379ms  :XXX-api:downloadSchemasTask
    205ms  :XXX-api:compileKotlin
   2224ms  :XXX-server:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin
    228ms  :XXX-server:kaptKotlin
    922ms  :XXX-server:compileTestKotlin
  57576ms  :XXX-server:test
```

**UPDATE**: When I turn on INFO log level in Gradle, I am seeing that app context is being initialized very slow. I also added: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m` in my `gradle.properties`. Without any effect.

**SOLUTION**: Do NOT use JDK17. With JDK14 it is all good.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have couple of tests classes ?
if so note the Lifecycle annotation.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseTest {

  @MockBean
  protected SomeBean someBean;

  @Autowired
  protected SomeBean2 someBean2;

  @BeforeAll
  public void setUp() {
    ..
  }
}
```

Now inherit from this BaseTest couple of tests classes. The initialization of the Spring context will be one time per `gradle test`

Comment: I deleted all other tests, I have one single test, which takes 50s to initialize the context.

Comment: Adding more logging can reveal where the time is being spent, compared to normal run. This can be done (at Gradle) with this for example: `tasks.withType(Test) { testLogging.showStandardStreams = true }`