# How h2 works in springboot test cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, h2

I am using springboot and H2 database for test cases.

I have multiple test classes each annotated with @SpringBootTest.
Each class has multiple test methods annotated with @Test

My doubt is, will h2 database be cleared

1. after each test method(annotated with @Test) execution or
2. after each test class(annotated with @SpringBootTest) execution or
3. after running all the test cases present in the application.

If case1 is true, then need to load the data to database in the @Before method which will be executed before each test method?

If case2 is true, then need to load the data to db in the @BeforeClass method which will be executed before each class execution.

If case3 is true, then if i load all the data to db in a test case, how to make it run first before all other test cases run.

What is the appropriate place to load the data to database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know about H2 clearance (except testing with break-points), but I would suggest to inherit the separate tests from a base class (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473706/8978587).
Put in the base class a member: `private static boolean dbCreated = false`,
and in the @BeforeAll do `if (! dbCreated) { populateData(); dbCreated = true; }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to know how h2 actually works based on that i can organize the data loading code.

Answer (score 1):

database-rider could be useful for initializing your H2 database with data before each test case.  See https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider

Comment: Does h2 clears the db after running each test case?